# Compile and run ARM assembly code via SSH on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, c, linux, assembly, ssh

I am trying to run some ARM assembly codes on Snapdragon 810 development board to evaluate performance on Cortex-A53 and A57 processors. My codes are nothing to do with android applications and they are C/Assembly coeds. Moreover, I want to get remote access to the board preferably via SSH and run gcc commands. The board default OS in Android Lollipop and my first intention was to install Linux on it to make things work desirably. However, Qualcomm customer support informed me that Linux isn't supported by this board and I have to deal with Android.

I've already searched over various forums. Some of them suggest to root the Android device, install [QuickSSHD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.quicksshd) or [SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid) on the device and simply SSH to it. However, I am not sure if the provided console has the capability of running `gcc` commands, generating executable and running it. Others, suggest to generate executable using cross-compilation and push the executable via `adb` console and run it on the Android device. This approach makes more sense, but I need to have remote access via SSH to the board and edit my code on the device continuously.

My question is, what is the best and easiest approach to get remote access  via SSH to this device, compile and run C/ARM Assembly code, transfer files and get the real timing of my codes?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross compile is the easiest option to generate the executable. Else you will have to port GCC to the target first. Don't even bother.

And Adb is a lot better when dealing with Android devices as you need not install any additional applications/executables to get it working. Adb can work on TCP connection as well. So there is no need of SSH for the task. And if the device is rooted, "adb root" followed by "adb shell" would give you the root console.

Comment: In my case, I need to count cpu clock cycles for a specific function in my code. If I cross-compile the code on my laptop and push the executable via adb and run it on adb terminal, am I going to get correct timing on Android device?

Comment: You should. The case with ssh or natively compiled is not going to be any different

Comment: Thanks, I give it a try then